# expected scalar type Long but found Float

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, tensor

This code uses pytorch. It is a NLP machine learning model. I am facing problem with the model part.

```
16     labels=labels.type(torch.LongTensor)
     17     print(labels.type())
---> 18     outputs= model(labels)
     19     loss=criterion(outputs.type(torch.LongTensor), labels)
     20     optimizer.zero_grad()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    112 
    113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float
```

I tried converting label to LongTensor. But that did not fix, the error. This is my code:

```
learning_rate=0.01
output_size=len(products)
num_epochs=5
hidden_size=50
input_size=len(all_words)

criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
model=NeuralNet(input_size,hidden_size,output_size)
optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)
#since it is multiclass

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  for (words, i) in xy:
    labels=bag_of_words(words,all_words)
    labels=torch.from_numpy(labels)
    labels=labels.type(torch.LongTensor)
    print(labels.type())
    outputs= model(labels)
    loss=criterion(outputs.type(torch.LongTensor), labels)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Kindly help me out with what I can do to fix this error. Which variable is the error referring to? Will there be a problem with the loss function also?

Answer (score 0):

What i think is happening is that your `labels` tensor is a `LongTensor` because it contains the labels of your data. When you pass a `LongTensor` input to a linear layer you get an error because the linear layer has a matrix of weights that are floats.
Try changing your code to:

```py
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  for (words, i) in xy:
    labels=bag_of_words(words,all_words)
    labels=torch.from_numpy(labels)
    outputs= model(labels.type(torch.FloatTensor))
    loss=criterion(outputs, labels)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

The expected input types of the loss (`criterion`) are the predicted probabilities (`FloatTensor`) and the input labels (`LongTensor`).